# Как задать формат времени (01, 02, 03)

Tags: java, время

Как задать формат времени, например 01, 02, 03,  а точнее у меня есть
такая часть кода :

```
if(minutes < 10){//когда минуты меньше 10 
                minutes = "0" + minutes;//Задать формат 00 для чисел меньше 10 пример
                //01, 02, 03, 04, 05
            }
        }
```

она должна прибавлять не поддающееся к арифметическим действиям (сложение, вычитание) число 0 к минутам. А оно выводит просто 1:5 (хотя должно 1:05, как и обычные часы у компьютера или телефона)

переменные :

```
int hours = 24;
int minutes = 65;
```

Answer (score 1):

код:

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d",1,2);
```

Вывод:

```
01:02
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `minutes` типа `int`. Когда вы пишите `"0" + minutes` вы складываете `String + int` и в итоге получаете `String`.

И результат сложения типа `String` вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной типа `int`.

Вы можете создать переменную для строкового представления минут, и в нее сохранять измененные минуты.

Например:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int minutes = 5;
      String min_str = "";
      if(minutes < 10){
          min_str = "0" + minutes;
      } else {
          min_str = Integer.toString(minutes);
      }
      System.out.println(min_str);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
05
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (minutes < 10){//когда минуты меньше 10 
            String minutes_str = "0" + minutes;//Задать формат 00 для чисел меньше 10 пример
            //01, 02, 03, 04, 05
        }
    }
```

Comment: не работает, похожее я пробовал

Comment: Неправильно пробовали. 01 - это строка. Число вы не получите. Вот и переводите в строку